# Working with dates in Entity Framework Code First - what is the current best practice?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Historically EF (Code First) did not have a way to enforce UTC dates and times to be stored or loaded (correct me if I am wrong) as UTC. Is that still the case with the newer versions? Is there a current recommended way to deal with dates and times in EF in a server timezone independent way without having to pollute the code base with conversions all over the place?

Comment: Also if someone can point me to a document describing the EF behavior when dealing with dates and time... My google-fu has failed me.

Comment: I know this is an EF question, and I hate to thread bomb, but nHibernate has `UtcDateTime`. :-)